# Building own Android with own UI for Vodafone Smart Tab

Tags: android, build, porting, tablet, android-source

We are working on experimental project and we need to build own Android and replace it with our own UI for Vodafone Smart Tab which comes with Android 3.2. As a resource I am using http://source.android.com/ and http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1_H4AlQaNa0.

My Questions are:

Will I need some special vendor code to port the build to Vodafone Smart Tab?

Will there be some problem replacing the common Android UI? I need to replace the system UI not just create some application.

Will I be able to use the latest Android version or do I have to use Android 3.2 that is originally distributed with the device?